# IIF statement in calculated measure has unexpected behavior in certain cases

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, olap-cube, iif

I have a set of status and substatus values in the cube browser and i want to get the max of insertion date for this pair only when the status=1 and substatus=1

I created a measure that has the following expression:

```
    IIF(([Trans Tasks FFMS Farah GVV].[Task Status].&[1],[Trans Tasks FFMS Farah GVV].[Task Sub Status].&[2]), 
    '-', Min([Measures].[Minimum Insertion DT]))
```

When a certain task has a status 1 and substatus 2 this works as expected but when a task does not have these values the value is calculated and displayed anyways!

What could be the cause of this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

`IIf` needs a ***condition*** as the first argument, hence you would have to write

```
IIF([Trans Tasks FFMS Farah GVV].[Task Status].CurrentMember IS [Trans Tasks FFMS Farah GVV].[Task Status].&[1]
     AND
    [Trans Tasks FFMS Farah GVV].[Task Sub Status].CurrentMember IS [Trans Tasks FFMS Farah GVV].[Task Sub Status].&[2]), 
    '-',
    [Measures].[Minimum Insertion DT]
   )
```

This is in contrast to `SCOPE` which needs a ***set*** as its argument.

Furthermore, I do not think you need the `Min` around the measure, a measure is defined at each combination of aggregated or unaggregated attributes.